# Spring Security / Keycloak: Securing the same request path with multiple realms

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I'd like users in two different realms (eg human users and S2S users) to access the same rest endpoint. All of multi-tenancy examples I can find (eg [keycloak multi-tenancy docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_multi_tenancy)) suggest implementing a `KeycloakConfigResolver` to pick a single realm based on the request path. Eg:

```java
public class PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {
    private final KeycloakDeployment realm1Deployment;
    private final KeycloakDeployment realm2Deployment;

    public PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver() throws IOException {
        realm1Deployment = buildDeployment("realm1.json");
        realm2Deployment = buildDeployment("realm2.json");
    }

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request request) {
        String path = request.getRelativePath();
        return path.startsWith("clients/") ? realm1Deployment : realm2Deployment;
    }

    private static KeycloakDeployment buildDeployment(String path) throws IOException {
        return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(new ClasspathResource(path).getInputStream());
    }
}
```

But this requires me to pick a single realm per request path.

I want different functionality, I'd like to try authenticating the request against multiple realms and pick the first the succeeds. I feel this would be the logical way to support multiple realms for a single URI but I'm open to suggestions for achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

Since Keycloak provides OAuth2 functionality, you do not necessarily need to use the keycloak adapters (a lot of them are being deprecated because of this, even, see [here](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/02/adapter-deprecation)). Instead you can just rely on the built in functionality of Spring Security.

An example of how to configure JWT Authentication for Spring Security with multiple issuers looks like this:

```java
JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver = new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver
    ("https://idp.example.org/issuerOne", "https://idp.example.org/issuerTwo");

http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)
    );
```

The separate issuer URLs in your case would be the issuer URLs of your respective realms. This example is taken directly from the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#_resolving_the_tenant_by_claim), it also contains samples on how to achieve the same with XML configuration, should you prefer to use that.

Of course, migrating away from the adapter, if you're already using it might not be easy, but since the adapter is going away in the long term anyways, it might be worth evaluating doing so as early as possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a new service so I'm not bound to `keycloak-spring-security-adapter`. Can you point to any documentation about this being deprecated? There's more than just the issuer URL in the deployment json files (eg realm, resource, ssl-required, use-resource-role-mappings, public-client etc) can you give an overview of how I would pass these to the issuer if not using the adapter?

Comment: This is actually a bit of work. At $job we have a custom library that does this for us, which we can easily reuse in all of our spring services. For example, we use https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction to extract realm and client roles, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-validation-custom to extract and verify audiences, etc. It's a larger one-time effort, but worth it if you plan to use multiple services

Comment: It feels like your custom library is doing a similar job to `keycloak-spring-security-adapter`? So seems like it's useful to have the adapter

Comment: @lance-java see my answer, you have links to [Keycloak adpaters deprecation announcement](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187) and to an [alternate adapter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-security-oauth2-webmvc-addons) supporting multi-tenancy from properties.

Answer (score 0):

The Keycloak adapters deprecation is announced [there](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

You should have a look at [this OpenID adapter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server) I wrote. It works out of the box with as many issuers as you need and solves quite a few of keycloak spring-boot adapter limitations:

- compatible with webmvc (servlets) and webflux (reactive) apps
- spring boot 3 ready (does not extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)
- no adherence to Keycloak (works with any OpenID authorization-server)
- tooling for security unit testing

Basic tutorial [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication).